# On street parking in the UK

Tags: uk, automobiles, england

This is more a question about UK parking etiquette, couldn’t find a more suitable SE Site.
In the UK, I’m getting a car, but parking where I live is very limited. 
At the same time, about 5 minutes walk, in a more built up but still suburbian area, there are similar dead end streets with some garage units at the end, and small parking lots next to them. There is usually a space or two empty (on the weekends). No signs as to access rights/limitations.
Would I be wrong/inconsiderate if I parked my car there for the night?
UPD
[image: A satellite image of an area as an example]
An example of an area
Naturally, I’ve searched high and low for any signs that would specify who is allowed to park there, but found nothing. Some of the vehicles appear to have been there for a while. 
I’d gladly rent a driveway/garage, but supply is almost nonexistent

Comment: Anywhere there is limited parking people can get territorial. Why not try to speak to some residents and find out if it really is unrestricted parking. If the community has a Facebook page why not ask there too? Some people might rent out their driveway when they aren't using it. For instance someone might work night shifts thus leaving their driveway vacant.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ might be the place to ask.

Comment: If parking is hard to find in your area, it seems unlikely the parking lots would be unrestricted. Are you sure there are no signs anywhere?

Comment: Who owns the property where you are considering parking?

Comment: Is the question about on-street or off-street parking? That is, are spaces in question part of the public road, or land next to the road but not part of it?

Comment: I am afraid there is no stack exchange site where this question really fits, likely this is the best. But better is to ask locally, people living there or the local council.

Comment: You could also talk to any of your own neighbors that have cars to find out what they do.

Comment: Where in the UK? Which street? Can you take a picture of the free spaces you mention? I fear as is this question lacks information to be answerable.

Comment: Being "right" and "not getting angry notes left on your car telling you not to park in their spot" are not mutually exclusive in these circumstances :)

Comment: @Moo - Not just angry notes, there's also a possibility of keys scraped down your car...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's on the street, it's usually fine, provided you're not blocking anyone in, if it's on the parking lot next to the garage, this is probably private property and you can't park on it.

In terms of communities to ask, as canonacer mentioned, use a local Facebook group or sign up to nextdoor.com.

You can find plenty of apps online by googling "Rent a parking space" where you will be able to pay your neighbour per day/week/month to use a space available on a private property. Just ensure they have permission to rent the [space.](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/london/renting-out-a-drive-risks-you-20000-fine-8739073.html)

Comment: Honestly, this is the answer; plus one from me.  It is true that some people in the UK get territorial about the on-street parking that happens to be outside their houses.  But they are simply wrong to do so, and I have never seen any good reason to indulge them.  If it's on-street, and there are no posted restrictions / kerb markings, park there, and ignore any local Gauleiters who presume to lay claim to something that isn't theirs.

Comment: @MadHatter couldn't agree more. If it's a road that has issues then it will be permitted, if it's not been then it means there is plenty of space or you need to bring it up with the council. Not the people who park there